# How to make a voice sound like it is underwater?

Tags: sound-effects, audacity, underwater

The goal is to alter the sound of voice so it sounds as the listener is underwater or in the womb.

I've got some experience with Audacity, so I'm most interested in how to do it using Audacity.

And here is the link to the original question that [inspired this question](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/conlang/message/180800).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd look for a VST plugin with a water preset. Several of them are discussed here: http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=174619

I think several effects are required reverb, pitch sweeps, etc.

Some generic underwater effects recommendations here: http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/underwater